# Issue with case sensitivity on windows

Tags: linux, windows, git

The problem is: We developing JAVA code and some of us works in linux and me in windows. As I cloned our repo then it turned out that in the same directory we have a directory in upper case and another one with lower case. Linux it is not a problem of course but in windows yes. It comes from our 3pp code so no renaming allowed. Due to this the repo messed up and files seems to be modified constantly. Do anyone know a solution for such problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to rename at least one of them consistently.  Git allows a decent renaming, so no problems from this side.

I would talk to the 3pp developer about in which hell he wants to burn for naming two directories like this, only distinguishable by case.

Comment: Not the renaming is the problem. The whole build script stuff and Makefile modification also have to be calculated. That part if a *#%@ mess. And we do not allowed to touch that.

Comment: A German proverb goes like this:  Wash me, but do not make me wet.  I think that fits your situation quite well.

Answer (score -1):

I once tried enabling the case-sensitivity in Windows, try this guide:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725747.aspx

Comment: That only applies to the NFS server. The file system itself remains case-insensitive but case-preserving.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I ahve windows 7 I do not know if this tutorial valid for it or not. I check it later. Or get a linux.